# Differentiability of $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, where $|x-y - (f(x) -f(y))| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

**Question:**
If $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous function that satifies $|x-y - (f(x) -f(y))| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that $f$ is differentiable at 0.

**My attempt:**
Let $y=0$. Then $|(f(x)-f(0)) - x| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x|$. Then $\frac{|(f(x)-f(0)) - x|}{|x|} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

I know I need to show that $\frac{|(f(x)-f(0)) - Mx|}{|x|} \rightarrow 0$ for some linear transformation $M$, but I'm at a loss as to how to use the condition. In particular, the $\frac{1}{2}$ is fixed, so I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: By [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher's_theorem) the function $x-f(x)$ seems to be differentiable almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x+\frac{1}{2}x\sin(1/x) & \text{if} & x\ne 0, \\
0 & \text{if} & x=0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then
$$
|f(x)-f(0)-x|=\left|\frac{1}{2}x\sin(1/x)\right|\le \frac{1}{2}|x|
$$
Clearly, $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Note. In fact, there exists a much simpler counterexample:
$$
g(x)=x+\frac{|x|}{2}.
$$

Comment: Does this change if I add the continuity condition?

Comment: I have changed this in the question.

Comment: The function in this answer is continuous.

Comment: The function in my example is also continuous.

Comment: Does this function hold the property of the original problem, though? When $y$ doesn't have to be $0$. I mean, this is a counterexample for the attempt, but not for the problem, right?

Comment: @AnilCh yeah, note that $g(x)-x=\frac{|x|}{2}$, so the inequality becomes $||x|-|y||\le|x-y|$ which is true by triangle inequality.